# asp menu showing differently in browsers

Tags: c#, asp.net, css, visual-studio-2010, menu

I have a web application that has a menu bar on top of the page. This menu bar is showing fine in Internet explorer 9 however in chrome it is showing incorrectly. I don't really know how to make this css file a cross browser css file.
here is how it shows in IE.
[image]

and here is how it shows in chrome.
[image]

my css is as follows:

```
div.hideSkiplink
{
    background-color: #796540;
    width: 100%;
    height: 56px;
    margin: 0px 5px 20px 0px;
}

div.menu
{
    padding: 1px 0px 1px 8px;
    margin: 5px 0px 5px 0px;
}

div.menu ul
{
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    width: auto;
}
```

and here is my page markup

```
   <div class="clear hideSkiplink">
                <asp:Menu ID="NavigationMenu" runat="server" CssClass="menu" EnableViewState="False"
                    IncludeStyleBlock="False" Orientation="Horizontal" BackColor="#F7F6F3" DynamicHorizontalOffset="2"
                    Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="0.8em" ForeColor="#7C6F57" StaticSubMenuIndent="10px"
                    DataSourceID="SiteMapDataSource1" OnMenuItemDataBound="NavigationMenu_MenuItemDataBound">
                </asp:Menu>
            </div>
```

can somebody please help me?

Comment: I would like to see the link to try to fix it. Can you put it?

Comment: its an intra net website

Comment: Ohh sorry than, can you put the example of html into jsfiddle?

Comment: wait, let me see what i can do.. it will be first time i use jsfiddle

Comment: try this http://jsfiddle.net/hTz7X/

Comment: Ive Updated both images .. have a look as to how they look

Comment: It does not work, ohhh and put baked html not asp.controls

Comment: i have updated jsfiddle link... please check back

Comment: or email me here: aathar at gmail and i will give you remote access so that you can have look

Answer (score 0):

try override default parameters of li paddings, li margins,hideskipling paddings

Comment: li { margin:<value>; padding:<value>;}  .hideSkiplink{padding:<value>;}

Answer (score 0):

Try changing width: 100%; to something fix/constant. Alternatively, try reading this post http://fabenterprises.wordpress.com/2009/03/21/aspnet-menu-not-rendering-correctly-in-googles-chrome/